# Using logstash for email alert

Tags: email, logstash, elastic-stack

I installed logstash 5.5.2 in our windows server and I would like to send an email alert when I identify some sentences.
My output section is the following:

```
output {
    tcp {
        host => "host.com"
        port => 1234
        codec => "json_lines"
    }
    if  "The message was Server with id " in [log_message]  {
        email {
            to => "<myName@company.com>"
            from => "<otherName@company.com>"
            subject => "Issue appearance"
            body => "The input is: %{incident}"
            domain => "smtp.intra.company.com"
            port => 25
            #via => "smtp"
        }
    }
}
```

During my debug I got the following messages:

```
[2017-09-11T13:19:39,181][ERROR][logstash.plugins.registry] Problems loading a plugin with {:type=>"output", :name=>"email", :path=>"logstash/outputs/email", :error_message=>"NameError", :error_class=>NameError
[2017-09-11T13:19:39,186][DEBUG][logstash.plugins.registry] Problems loading the plugin with {:type=>"output", :name=>"email"}
[2017-09-11T13:19:39,195][ERROR][logstash.agent           ] Cannot create pipeline {:reason=>"Couldn't find any output plugin named 'email'. Are you sure this is correct? Trying to load the email output plugin resulted in this error: Problems loading the requested plugin named email of type output.
```

Which I guess says that I don't have the email plugin installed.
Can someone suggest a way to fix this?
Using another solution is not an option, just in case that someone suggests it.

Thanks and regards,
Fotis

Answer (score 0):

I tried to follow the instructions in the [official documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/offline-plugins.html)
But the option of creating an offline plugin pack didn't work.
So what I did, was to create a running logstash instance on my client, run the command to install the output-email plugin `logstash-plugin install logstash-output-email` and afterwards I copied this instance on my server(which had no internet access).